# Upserting on embedded document

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document strucutre

```
{
    "_id" : "NmBYYasdsa",
    "objectId" : "asdsd"
    "text" : "test",
    ....
    "publishedAt" : ISODate("2015-05-28T15:31:51Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-05-28T15:31:51Z"),
    "data" : {
        .....
        "likeCount" : 0,
        "replyCount" : 0
    }
}
```

That is use to synchronise my database with an external API. To do this, I poll the API once every minute and do a bulk upsert, matching on the object id to keep my database up to date.

Problem is that the `data` subdocument doesn't get updated when upserting, any ideas as to why?

My bulkwrite method

```
Mongo.Collection.prototype.upsertBulk = function(matcher, documents, options) {
  if (_.isEmpty(documents)) { throw Error('Empty list of documents provided'); }
  options = options || {};

  var operations = documents.map(function(_document) {
    _document._id = Random.id();

    var operation = {
      updateOne: {
        filter: {},
        update: { $set: _document },
        upsert: true
      },
    };
    operation['updateOne']['filter'][matcher] = _document[matcher];

    return operation;
  });

  this.__mongoCollection(function(collection) {
    collection.bulkWrite(operations, options, function(error, result) {
      if (error) { throw error; }
      return result;
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of what is contained in `_document` since you seem to be processing an array of input. You also seem to be mixing syncronous "return" statements with "async" logic which will not work well. In that case your `function()` would be better off taking a "callback" as an argument for processing of the result and error.